# how to make the child div not alert something when i only defined the parent div's click function 

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

this is my code:

```
<div id="a" style="position:absolute;width:200px;height:200px;background:red;word-wrap:break-word;">
            <div id="b" style="width:50px;height:50px;background:blue;"></div>
</div>
```

the script is :

```
$( "#b" ).draggable({ containment: 'parent' });
$('#a').click(function(e){
        alert(e.pageX)
        //return false;
    })
```

i want to alert when i click the red div , not the blue div ,

the demo is here :http://jsfiddle.net/KwYjr/2/

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Test the `e.target` for its ID.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/KwYjr/6/

```
$('#a').click(function(e){
    if( e.target.id === 'a' ) {
        alert(e.pageX);
    }
    //return false;
});
```

Another option would be to add a click handler to your `#b` element that calls `e.stopPropagation()`, but I wouldn't recommend it. There are better ways to go (like the one above) than to assign a handler just for the purpose of stopping propagation.

---

**EDIT:**

Another way to run the test above, would be to do a direct comparison of the elements, instead of using its ID:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/KwYjr/8/

```
if( e.target === this ) {
    alert(e.pageX);
}
```

Comment: Voted up. Exactly what i came to post.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `event.stopPropagation()` like this it works:

```
$( "#b" ).draggable({ containment: 'parent' }).click(function(e){ e.stopPropagation(); });

$('#a').click(function(e){
    alert(e.pageX);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

use

event.preventDefault()

```
http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/
```

Comment: The `preventDefault()` method won't help in this case. This is used to prevent the default behavior of an element, like a link for example. A `<div>` element doesn't have a default behavior. :o)

Comment: I tried that out on jsFiddler with the OP code. Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @patrick you are right , i got ,your code is working , thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagate();
```

Comment: preventDefault doesn't work in this situation , see patricks explanation , divs won't have any default behavior.